# Why is this one answer attracting so many spam edits?

Tags: discussion

My answer https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/1012/117  attacks about 2 attempts to edit every day, always trying to link to some product or another.  Any insight into why this particular answer is being attacked?

Answer (score 5):

There are also some other answers in this thread that are "under attack" it is not only your answer.

One reason why these answer could have been chosen is that they are short; as soon as it would be longer than 400 characters there would be an extra check when the complete content is changed.

I rather doubt there is any other reason than the short lengths of some answers there (and bad luck); no obvious keyword that could trigger this comes to mind and looking through the list of rejected edits one finds a couple of similar attempts elsewhere where the anwser is also short.

In any case, if you want to do something directly, you could try to get the answer above 400 characters. Other than that, the best thing to do is to continue to reject the edits as vandalism. The information attached is picked up by the spam-prevention mechanisms of the site and eventually this should go away as it will be blocked before it hits the site.

Sorry for the inconveniences!

Answer (score 4):

We don't know exactly why some answers become [honeypots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_(computing)), but we have a system to [use spam edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237055/1438) to feed a spam blocking system. Looking at the network as a whole, this has proved to be very successful. But the cost is that people such as yourself are the victim of your own personal suggested edit spam pings.

As [quid mentioned](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/376/33), you could pad out your answer, but that's sub-optimal. We are aware of the problem and are working on better ways to handle this type of spam. (I'm going to talk to Tim on Monday so that I understand what we can actually do now. I'm still pretty new at this!)